# plupload / flash / Amazon S3 / unique_names

Tags: flash, amazon-s3, plupload

I am working on an implementation of plupload using flash to upload files to Amazon S3. I have the uploading of the files to S3 working perfectly except for one small problem. The issue is the setting 'unique_names' is not working. I always end up with file in S3 with the original file name. After some debugging I do see that the unique file name is created and passed on to the flash SWF for uploading but it is never used. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: didn't find even a word 'unique' in plupload source except 'com\plupload\File.as:82: characters 15-21 : * @param id Unique indentifier for the file.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help:
http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=4321#p4321

You have to set up a file renaming function by writing custom code for the UploadFile Event.

This is what I did:

```
        preinit : {

         UploadFile: function(up, file) {
             up.settings.multipart_params.key = 'adjsdlasjdasdas.jpg';
         }
        },
```

Replace 'adjsdlasjdasdas.jpg'; with your custom function for renaming.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution at https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/254. This is how I used the code. First it removes the extension, then I create a unique ID and last I add the extension. I also added a folder name using a php variable, this is not necessary but I think it will keep your bucket more organized.

```
preinit : {

    BeforeUpload : function(up,file){

        // Get the file extension 
        var file_name = file.name;
        var extension = file_name.split(".").pop();

        // Create a random ID
        var new_id = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
        for( var i=0; i < 10; i++ )
        new_id += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

        // Change the name NOTE I use a php variable to create a folder on S3
        up.settings.multipart_params.key = "<?php echo $foldername ?>/"+n+new_id+"."+extension;
        up.settings.multipart_params.Filename = "<?php echo $foldername ?>/"+n+new_id+"."+extension;
        }

},
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the file is unique before you upload the file. Here is my code.

```
UploadFile: function(up, file) {
        pluploadlog('[UploadFile]', file);
        // You can override settings before the file is uploaded
        var filename = file.name;
        file.newname = '01'+ filename ;///add your own function here to create something unique. 
         up.settings.multipart_params = {
                   'key': mybucketsubdirectory + filename, 
                  'Filename': filename, 
                  'acl': 'public-read',
                  'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
                  'AWSAccessKeyId' : '<?php echo $accessKeyId; ?>',
                  'policy': '<?php echo $policy; ?>',
                  'signature': '<?php echo $signature; ?>'
                };
      },
```

Then on your file upload look at the file.newname you added previously.

```
FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
          if (file.status == 5){
             console.log(file.newname); // If you need to get back the new unique name
            uploadSuccess(file, info); 
          }else{
            showItemError(file);
          }
        }
```